# Oracle external loader - loading double quotes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, external-tables

I have external table and need to insert data as follow. But when I skip quotes using optionally enclosed by '"' on loader column called variables not reading as inside that column got quotes. (Overall table is empty)

Any one can suggest me any ideas?

I have option to do this by using FIELDS TERMINATED BY '"~~~"' and read data to table and do data modification. But instead of doing this is there any way that I can handle this on external table level?

**Input Data**

```
"apple"~~~"05-APR-2021 13.42.56.480000"~~~"Add"~~~"host"~~~"["Yes"]"~~~"Filter"
"Orange"~~~"05-APR-2021 19.57.06.084000"~~~"Add"~~~"cow: purpose"~~~"["A","catch","Other","A and admin","A and other","A and othe"~~~"Chart"
```

**Expected Out put on table**

| Name  | TIMESTAMP  | ACTION | Description | Variables      | Option|
+-------+------------+--------+--------------+---------------+--------+
| apple  | 05-APR-2021 | Add   | host        | ["Yes"]         |  Filter |
| Orange | 05-APR-2021 | Add  | cow: purpose| ["A","catch","Other","A and admin","A and other","A and othe" |   Chart|
+-------+------------+--------+--------------+---------------+--------+

**Code used to read to table and no data reading to below table**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable_XT
(
        Name VARCHAR2(36 CHAR),
        TIMESTAMP       TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTION  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
        Description VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
        Variables VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
        Option VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)

)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY def_dir1
ACCESS PARAMETERS
(
        records delimited by newline skip 1
        data is little endian
        string sizes are in characters
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '"~~~"'
        optionally enclosed by '"'
        missing field values are null
reject rows with all null fields (
    Name CHAR(36) NULLIF "Name " =' ',
    "TIMESTAMP" CHAR DATE_FORMAT TIMESTAMP MASK "DD-MON-YYYY",
    "ACTION" CHAR(50) NULLIF "ACTION" =' ',
    "Description " CHAR(100) NULLIF "Description " =' ',
    "VARIABLES" CHAR(100) NULLIF "VARIABLES" =' ',
     "Option" CHAR(50) NULLIF "Option" =' '

)
)
LOCATION ('mytest.txt'))
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```